# Should you use parameters in css files for React?

Tags: css, reactjs, parameters

I am using React and when I update my live application there is usually problems with the new CSS not being loaded.

Right now it just say:

```
import './app.css'
```

For a html website I would just add a parameter. Can I add this in a React application as well? Something like:

```
import './app.css?v=1.2'
```

Or is this not recommended for a React application?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the problem with the way your application is compiled I think this has to do with how your browser caches `CSS`. When you load a website your browser caches files and if it reloads and sees the same name as in the cache it will not download a new version but use the old one. I do not know why this is showing up because hot reloading should refresh this but if you reload using `CTRL + Shift + R` (or `CMD + Shift + R`) it should not happen. For the specifics search on why cache is not getting cleared.

Comment: Yes, hard reloading will update it, but I would like it not to be necessary. Thats why I wondering if adding a parameter is a good idea for a React application.. Or if it will give me more problems as I have not seen anyone else use it for React.

Comment: When running it in dev it should just reload it normally and I think if you build it for `production` then it will change the file name automatically. The only problem then remains is that it also caches the HTML page.
Is your question about running it in dev with `react-scripts` or when deploying it after `npm run build`?

Comment: Its when deploying it with npm run build. Dev reloads it directly

Comment: I think sadly this is just how the browser works and that it caches it's `html` and `css`. In this case I think the build CSS will get a different tag but since the browser caches the HTML it will just get the old one. I sadly do not have the solution for you on this point the only thing to do is to set the `html meta tag` to cache none but then the whole caching puprose of the browser is gone. Good luck on your search anyway and if you find it I would love to know your solution.

Comment: But should I not add a parameter then? Or does it risk breaking anything?

Comment: You can but it does not really do anything when building your bundler will automatically add a suffix to the file something like `app-c8aras9.css`